# Combining rows in dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

I have a pandas dataframe like this [Dataframe Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6G0Y.png) and I want to combine the rows based on SI.No. columns as the rows from index 0 to 3 should be combined as one so that I should be having a single row for SI.No.= 1.0. The same rule should be applicable for other rows as well. The csv for the dataframe can be found on this link [csv file](https://github.com/Chauhan240/Chauhan240/blob/main/test_data.csv)
|

Comment: Please post sample data, expected output and what you have tried so far

Comment: and what do you mean by combined? Just concatenate the fields?

Comment: How should they be concatenated? Please provide the matching expected output for clarity

Comment: Plesae see [ask]: questions are better answered when providing a [mre], so not your whole data, but a representative sample, posted as text, along with an expected output

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to concatenate the non-NA cells as a single string, form groups with [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html) and use a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
out = (df.groupby(df['Sl.No.'].bfill())
         .agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna().astype(str)))
      )
```

Output:

```
       Sl.No.                                                                                             Institute                                   Course                                        GNDCD                              GNGND GNPHD                                        OBDCD                            OBGND OBPHD SCDCD                              SCGND                              STGND
Sl.No.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
1.0       1.0  Ambedkar Institute of Advanced Communication Technologies and Research, Geeta Colony, Delhi - 110092           Computer Science & Engineering    Min Rank - 4494 (06) Max Rank - 4494 (06)     Min Rank - 605 Max Rank - 1932        Min Rank - 12119 (06) Max Rank - 12119 (06)  Min Rank - 4181 Max Rank - 6326               Min Rank - 8930 Max Rank - 18677  Min Rank - 35295 Max Rank - 35295
2.0       2.0  Ambedkar Institute of Advanced Communication Technologies and Research, Geeta Colony, Delhi - 110092  Electronics & Communication Engineering   Min Rank - 9445 (06) Max Rank - 13172 (06)     Min Rank - 827 Max Rank - 5048        Min Rank - 16151 (06) Max Rank - 16151 (06)  Min Rank - 6663 Max Rank - 9982               Min Rank - 7454 Max Rank - 24487  Min Rank - 36691 Max Rank - 36691
3.0       3.0          Amity School of Engg. & Technology,580, Delhi Palam Vihar Road, Bijwasan, New Delhi - 110061           Computer Science & Engineering  Min Rank - 15142 (06) Max Rank - 15500 (06)    Min Rank - 4817 Max Rank - 9252                                                                                                  Min Rank - 26348 Max Rank - 47822                                   
4.0       4.0          Amity School of Engg. & Technology,580, Delhi Palam Vihar Road, Bijwasan, New Delhi - 110061  Electronics & Communication Engineering  Min Rank - 18580 (06) Max Rank - 18580 (06)   Min Rank - 9660 Max Rank - 14606                                                                                                  Min Rank - 47116 Max Rank - 47116                                   
5.0       5.0          Amity School of Engg. & Technology,580, Delhi Palam Vihar Road, Bijwasan, New Delhi - 110061                   Information Technology  Min Rank - 21212 (06) Max Rank - 21270 (06)   Min Rank - 1839 Max Rank - 11643                                                                                                  Min Rank - 43383 Max Rank - 43383                                   
6.0       6.0          Amity School of Engg. & Technology,580, Delhi Palam Vihar Road, Bijwasan, New Delhi - 110061    Instrumentation & Control Engineering  Min Rank - 28111 (06) Max Rank - 32219 (06)  Min Rank - 16310 Max Rank - 19696                                                                                                                                                                      
7.0       7.0          Amity School of Engg. & Technology,580, Delhi Palam Vihar Road, Bijwasan, New Delhi - 110061      Mechanical & Automation Engineering  Min Rank - 32430 (06) Max Rank - 36622 (06)   Min Rank - 8856 Max Rank - 18144                                                                                                  Min Rank - 34155 Max Rank - 34155                                   
8.0       8.0             Bhagwan Parshuram Institute of Technology,P.S.P. - 4, Sector - 17, Rohini, Delhi - 110085           Computer Science & Engineering   Min Rank - 9616 (06) Max Rank - 12745 (06)    Min Rank - 2442 Max Rank - 5122                                                                                                  Min Rank - 21121 Max Rank - 32876                                   
9.0       9.0             Bhagwan Parshuram Institute of Technology,P.S.P. - 4, Sector - 17, Rohini, Delhi - 110085     Electrical & Electronics Engineering  Min Rank - 23332 (06) Max Rank - 24692 (06)   Min Rank - 7780 Max Rank - 10716                                                                                                  Min Rank - 10183 Max Rank - 40576                                   
10.0     10.0             Bhagwan Parshuram Institute of Technology,P.S.P. - 4, Sector - 17, Rohini, Delhi - 110085  Electronics & Communication Engineering  Min Rank - 12848 (06) Max Rank - 22410 (06)    Min Rank - 5997 Max Rank - 8744                                                                                                  Min Rank - 27347 Max Rank - 41077                                   
11.0     11.0             Bhagwan Parshuram Institute of Technology,P.S.P. - 4, Sector - 17, Rohini, Delhi - 110085                   Information Technology  Min Rank - 11022 (06) Max Rank - 13517 (06)    Min Rank - 4399 Max Rank - 6320                                                                                                  Min Rank - 33486 Max Rank - 35583                                   
12.0     12.0     Bharati Vidyapeeth's College of Engineering (2nd Shift), A - 4, Paschim Vihar, New Delhi - 110063           Computer Science & Engineering    Min Rank - 8040 (06) Max Rank - 8221 (06)    Min Rank - 1404 Max Rank - 2778                                                                                                  Min Rank - 18827 Max Rank - 25405  Min Rank - 26369 Max Rank - 26369
13.0     13.0     Bharati Vidyapeeth's College of Engineering (2nd Shift), A - 4, Paschim Vihar, New Delhi - 110063  Electronics & Communication Engineering  Min Rank - 14613 (06) Max Rank - 16313 (06)    Min Rank - 4920 Max Rank - 5906                                                                                                  Min Rank - 23625 Max Rank - 36739                                   
14.0     14.0     Bharati Vidyapeeth's College of Engineering (2nd Shift), A - 4, Paschim Vihar, New Delhi - 110063                   Information Technology    Min Rank - 8557 (06) Max Rank - 9694 (06)    Min Rank - 3003 Max Rank - 3755                                                                                                  Min Rank - 26478 Max Rank - 34558
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Chauhan240/Chauhan240/main/test_data.csv', index_col=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really usefull if you provide a copy to paste minimal example that allows us to dive right into your problem.

Assuming you need the values concatenated, you can do the following.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [np.nan, "my", "1"],
    ["groupa", "values", "2"],
    [np.nan, "my", "3"],
    ["groupb", "values", "4"],
], columns=["group", "val1", "val2"])

# filling missing group values backwards
df.group.bfill(inplace=True)

# perform concatenation by joining the string with a blank
res = df.groupby("group").agg(lambda x: " ".join(x))

# output
print(res)
```

result has the text fields concatenated for each group (`SI.No` in your case)